# Rally SDK: adjust and check widget settings locally

Tags: javascript, rally

It is possible to define custom Setting fields and then return them in the function `getSettingsFields` from the Rally app. However, I couldn't find a place to view the settings when debugging the app during developemnt locally (i.e. by opening HTML with the app from disk outside Rally environment).

Does anybody know how to do this? Developing custom settings screen requires to constantly check the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right- unfortunately with 2.0rc3 it is pretty clumsy to develop settings since you need to keep building and pasting the code into Rally to test it.  The good news is that settings and menu options will be available externally in the upcoming 2.0 release early next year.

In the meantime you can trigger the settings by adding a button or other clickable component to your app and calling [showSettings](http://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.app.App-method-showSettings) on your app from your click handler:

```
_onClick: function() {
    this.showSettings();
}
```

Clicking save should then apply the settings to your local app instance.  You can then refresh your app by implementing the [onSettingsUpdate](http://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.app.App-method-onSettingsUpdate) template method.

```
onSettingsUpdate: function() {
   //redraw app
}
```